# how to add default text in woocommerce product description page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

there is anyway we can fix some text in product description when add product page come or anyway we could paste the text not snippest in product description. pease send any tutorial or any pugin that can help.

Answer (score 0):

use this code i think it works for you.

```
function filter_woocommerce_short_description( $post_excerpt )   {
$your_msg='your Text or any Message';
return $post_excerpt.'<br>'.$your_msg;}
```

Try this and let me know if it works will for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48444564/add-a-custom-field-value-below-product-title-in-woocommerce-archives-pages
Check this once